# RQuantLib package installation not working in ubuntu 14 on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rcpp

Not able to do - `"install.packages('RQuantLib')"` in `ubuntu`.
It worked pretty fine on windows.

I have installed `Rcpp` package already.
Would be great if someone could list down steps involved.
I am new to linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the [`quantlib`](http://quantlib.org/install/linux.shtml) libraries installed?

Comment: Are you aware that you can just do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rquantlib` ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Seems quantlib was not insalled due to insufficient space. Got it working now.